# Cmake produces file extensions in static library archives

Tags: c++, cmake

I recently switch from Autotools to CMake because CMake seems to be better for cross platform development and what I've noticed is when I build a static library of my C++ code all the files inside have a suffix .cpp.o

```
ar -t PA8/libgenericTZR.a 
genericTZR.cpp.o
```

I've looked at other libraries built by other tools and they don't do that. I'm not sure if this is really a bad thing but, how can I get CMake to build the static libraries without the .cpp added file extension?

This is my CMake File

```
add_executable(PA8 ISP_Charges.cpp genericTZR.cpp genericTZR.h)

set(LIBSRC genericTZR.c genericTZR.h)
add_library(genericTZR SHARED ${LIBSRC})
add_library(genericTZR SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:myObjects>)

add_library(genericTZR-static STATIC ${LIBSRC})
set_target_properties(genericTZR-static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME $

install (TARGETS PA8 DESTINATION bin)
install (TARGETS genericTZR genericTZR-static DESTINATION lib)
install (FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/PA8/genericTZR.h" DESTINA$
```

Thanks

Comment: `genericTZR.cpp.o` is not a static library. It is object file, a product of _compilation_ step. Once this step is finished, the object files it produced are _linked_ into a static library. Static libraries filenames typically have `.a` extension on Linux/Unix platforms.

Comment: yes but it is stored in the static library with the extra .cpp

Comment: This one does not have the extra extension 

ar -t /usr/lib/clang/3.4/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-i386.a  
asan_allocator2.o
asan_dll_thunk.o

Comment: Technically static libraries on POSIX systems (like Linux) are just uncompressed archives of object files (that's what `ar` and the `.a` extension stands for, archive).  The name of the files inside this archive is not used anywhere, and so does not really matter. That the object files are named `.cpp.o` at the end is just the way cmake works, there's nothing to do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread on cmake list](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/cmake-output-file-naming-td7581261.html) (and I agree with it), it is not a good idea to try to change the output file names.

Consider the example gave in the link:

```
 add_executable(foo foo.c foo.cpp)
```

Generated objects would be `foo.c.o` and `foo.cpp.o`. They would conflict if you forced them to have just the `.o` extension.

You can try to use the non-documented, internal, might-change-in-the-future

```
set(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1)
```

I don't know if they're still available or if works at all. I've never used them.

As comments on your post have clarified it, the names inside the static lib aren't really used, you shouldn't worry about them.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly also I would never have a foo.c and foo.cpp

Comment: @TaylorBioniks any sane person wouldn't but I couldn't put that there without a warning :) Also, things like that can happen if you create your source list with file(GLOB).

Comment: True, though the reason I wanted to change this was because autotools does not do it and to me  it looks unprofessional, though I may just be being picky.